# TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing in excel

Tags: python, excel, loops

Can someone help me? I'm having this error. I want to loop and insert all the data from wordnet into different column in excel. It will first read an excel document which have one column. Then, it will create other excel and generate the synonym word in a row and different column for each word.

This code generates the synonyms all in one column:

```
import nltk
import xlrd
import csv
import xlwt
import xlsxwriter
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\\runeza\Desktop\database.xlsx')
sheet_names = workbook.sheet_names()
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[0])

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet("test")
for col_idx in range(sheet.ncols):
    for row_idx in range(sheet.nrows):
        cell = sheet.cell(row_idx, col_idx).value #read content in column cell
        synonyms = []
        for syn in wordnet.synsets(cell):
            for l in syn.lemmas():
                #print(l.name())
                synonyms.append(l.name())
                a = set(synonyms)
        #print (a)
        ws.write(row_idx, col_idx,",".join(a))

wb.save("sample.xls")
```

I have modified the code to properly place the words in different columns:

```
import nltk
import xlrd
import csv
import xlwt
import xlsxwriter
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\\runeza\Desktop\database.xlsx')
sheet_names = workbook.sheet_names()
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[0])

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet("test")

for col_idx in range(sheet.ncols):
    for row_idx in range(sheet.nrows):
        cell = sheet.cell(row_idx, col_idx).value #read content in column cell
        synonyms = []

        for syn in wordnet.synsets(cell):
            for l in syn.lemmas():
                synonyms.append(l.name())
                a = set(synonyms)
        #print (a)

        for col_idx in range(len(a)):
            for row_idx in range(len(a[col_idx])):
                ws.write(col_idx, row_idx, a[col_idx][row_idx])

wb.save("sample.xls")
```

But it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\runeza\Documents\PythonCode\outputfile.py", line 29, in <module>
    for row_idx in range(len(a[col_idx])):
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

This is how my (C:\Users\runeza\Desktop\database.xlsx) looks:

[image: existing sheet]

This is my expected result:

[image]

Comment: I can't really help you unless I can see the document and I can't tell what are you trying to do. Obviously from your error the error, first you are using the same variable in two different loops (within) the `col_idx` and second the object does not support indexing means you can't access it by an index.

Comment: Please paste the `C:\\Users\\runeza\Desktop\database.xlsx ` document for for the question.

Comment: I have edit the question and insert how my document looks like. @ElvirMuslic

Comment: `a`  is a set. You cannot do `a[col_idx]`. What is the problem with your old code? Was that working?

Comment: my old code is working but I would like to make some changes. My old code only use one column and join all the synonym word by (,). For new code, I would like to make some changes, so that different word can be insert into different column.

Comment: can you post something like an expected result?

Answer (score 0):

For your need, I think  a `list` will be a better option. `set` objects does not support indexing (like a[0]).

Assuming that synonyms are to be added to rightside cells, you can do something like:

```
for col_idx in range(sheet.ncols):
    for row_idx in range(sheet.nrows):
        cell = sheet.cell(row_idx, col_idx).value #read content in column cell
        synonyms = []

        for syn in wordnet.synsets(cell):
            for l in syn.lemmas():
                synonyms.append(l.name())

        # Making the list elements distinct.
        synonyms = list(set(synonyms))

        for i in range(len(a)):
            ws.write(row_idx, col_idx+i, synonyms[i]) # Made an edit here.

wb.save("sample.xls")
```

Comment: I have edit your code " ws.write(row_idx, col_idx+i, synonyms[i] "  and its work as what i am expecting. However, the synonym word that i use is from wordnet and it repeat the same word if i'm not using set.

Comment: I have edit my question and show my expecting result. The only problem right now is the synonyms word provide from wordnet is keep repeating. I don't know how to solve it instead using set.

Comment: @runeza list elements can be made distinct by converting it to set and then back to list. I've added it to the answer.